# Replace values in r using case_when

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when

I'm trying to replicate some Stata code in r. In my df, there is a variable "time" and one "exposure" (both numeric, so with values like 1,2,3 etc.

This is what the original Stata code looks like:

```
replace time = (time - 31) if exposure == 0
```

And this is what I tried:

```
recoded_df <- recoded_df %>% mutate(time = case_when(exposure == 0 ~ (time - 31))
```

I get the error that there is an "unexpected symbol" in the code. But I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Could you please share a reproducible piece of your data by means of `dput(head(data))`? It's essential if you are to have any chances of getting relevant solutions.

Comment: Without sample data to test, your code looks right except that you are missing a `)` at the end. You probably also want to set a default of "no changes", `mutate(time = case_when(exposure == 0 ~ (time - 31), TRUE ~ time))`

Comment: In addition to sample data, I can't figure out how to get that error from this code: without the last right-paren, R just waits for me to close out the expression, no error. My guess is that you have something else, perhaps `mutate(time = case_when(...) time2 = foo(.))`, where there needs to be a comma (just a guess, though).

Comment: @GregorThomas, I tend to prefer that methodology as well, explicitly adding a default value, but `case_when` does default to `NA` which might be what the OP is intending. (idk)

Comment: @r2evans unexpected symbol is a pretty common error with unmatched parens. R will look to the next line, which may start with something that creates a syntax error if it was part of this line

Comment: Interesting. In emacs/ess, I cannot get "unexpected symbol" with this code, with or without the missing paren. Perhaps that's an ESS thing, not R, and I'm mis-placing the attribution. (Then again, I didn't try in context of a larger script, so that might be the triggering agent.)

Comment: And @r2evans my assumption is the Stata code shared would not make the non-transformed values NA.

Comment: Yeah, okay, my STATA is below weak. Thanks for the perspective!

Comment: Yes, mine as well, but it reads to me like a data.table `data[exposure == 0, time := time - 31]` (which is an idiom I hope `dplyr` implements eventually. I saw a nice proposal on Twitter for a `where()` clause that would work similarly to `across()` but for selecting rows to operate on...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two possibilities how you can achieve your task with a fake dataframe:

```
# fake dataframe:
df <- tribble(
  ~time, ~exposure,
  100, 0,
 70, 1, 
  90, 0, 
  60, 1, 
  50, 0
)

# 1. with mutate and ifelse
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(time = ifelse(exposure == 0, time-31, time))

# 2. with base R and ifelse
df$time <- ifelse(df$exposure == 0, df$time - 31, df$time)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  exposure = c(0, 1),
  time = c(81, 20)
)

df %>%
  mutate(
    time = case_when(exposure == 0 ~ time - 30,
                     TRUE ~ time)
  )

  exposure time
1        0   51
2        1   20
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`, `fifelse`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, time := fifelse(!exposure, time - 30,  time)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `ifelse` from base R should cover this:

```r
recoded_df$time = ifelse(recoded_df$exposure == 0,
                         recoded_df$time - 31, recoded_df$time)
```